# OVH Public Cloud - Adding region to exisiting vRack

Tags: networking, datacenter, ovh

I have an OVH public cloud project with several instances connected between two datacenters
in vRack with the classic 192.168.0.0/24 range on the eth1 network interface.

The vRack was initially created to interconnect only two datacenters (DE and SBG), but after the recent fire I lost some instances and I would like to rearrange the project with other datacenters too in order to add geographical HA.

I checked openstack API and OVH documentation and I can't find a way to edit an existing vRack to add a region once created, so how should I proceed to add instances of another datacenter (eg UK) while maintaining the existing private connectivity / IPs ?

Do i necessarily have to create a new private network with new IPs and locations and reconfigure my project with the new IPs ? Or there's a way to create a second vRack without touching the first one ?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the OVHCloud API. It's very straightforward, you can use the web based API explorer to make API calls, so it can all be done within the browser.

The endpoint you are interested in is https://api.ovh.com/console/#/cloud/project/%7BserviceName%7D/network/private/%7BnetworkId%7D/region#POST.

To get `serviceName`, which is your project ID and `networkId` you can use the API as well.

Comment: Also, you will need to add a subnet for the region, which can also be done using the API.

Comment: Yes, done :) You made my day - Thank you very much !!